# Please give me a simple code : How to add CheckBox in ComboBox?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

Please Help me Out.

I have tried a lot but i can't do.

please give simple code

How to add CheckBox in ComboBox?

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  But even if you could would you like to explain why.  The purpose of a combobox is to make a single selection.

Comment: QComboBox provides a popup menu. Perhaps you mean to add a QCheckBox to a QGroupBox?

Comment: @K'Leg Of course you can do it, but it would involve reimplementing `paintEvent` to draw checkboxes in the drop down section, and obviously the mouse interactivity for them.  Howvever, it's far from "simple code" - it would be easiest to start by looking at the QComboBox source code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this (but it's not a combo box)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: No just providing a visual aid to confirm understanding of question since comments would have taken forever to explain what this image does in a few seconds.